# Append list to each div in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

Append list to each div in order.
I have a list of names created dynamically:

```
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>
      <h2>Name 1<br>
      Description</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Name 2<br>
      Description</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Name 3<br>
      Description</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And I want each of these `li` to be appendTo in order to these `.photo`, how would I do it?

```
  <div id="myCanvas">
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="./app/img/pinturas-1.png"/>
      <h2>Name 1<br>
      Description</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="./app/img/pinturas-2.png"/>
      <h2>Name 2<br>
      Description</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="./app/img/pinturas-3.png"/>
      <h2>Name 3<br>
      Description</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Updated my question.
This is what I want to achieve created dinamically:

```
  <div id="myCanvas">
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="./app/img/pinturas-1.png"/>
      <h2>Name 1<br>
      Description</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="./app/img/pinturas-2.png"/>
      <h2>Name 2<br>
      Description</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="./app/img/pinturas-3.png"/>
      <h2>Name 3<br>
      Description</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you want li to be sorted on the basis of name? have you tried anything from your end?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar No, just in order, first, second, third and so on...

Comment: can you post the expected html output to understand what exactly you are asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below logic to move `li` to matching `div` index.
You can iterate all divs and get the index, find child of li with matching index and append it to div.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#myCanvas .photo').each(function(){
     var index = $(this).index();
     //console.log($('#myList li:eq(' + index +')').html());
     //console.log(index);
     var $child = $('#myList li:eq(' + index +')').children();
     $(this).append($child);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
    <li>
      <h2>Name 1<br>
      Description</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Name 2<br>
      Description</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Name 3<br>
      Description</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="myCanvas">
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="./app/img/pinturas-1.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="./app/img/pinturas-2.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="./app/img/pinturas-3.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: happy to help you :)